# Is is possible to use function overloading in R?

Tags: r, overloading

Is it possible to use function overloading in R? I've seen answers to this question from 2013, but the language and its possibilities evolved a lot over time.
In my specific case, I'd like the following:

```
formFeedback <- function(success, message)
formFeedback <- function(feedback_object)
```

Is this at all possible? If not, what's the best practice? Should I use two different named functions, should I make all parameters optional, or should I force the users to always pass an object and make the other one impossible?

Comment: I guess you know about S3 methods, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no function overloading in R, though there are a few object systems that accomplish similar things.  The simplest one is S3:  it dispatches based on the class attribute of the first argument (though there are a few cases where it looks at other arguments).

So if your `feedback_object` has a class attribute, you could make your first form the default and your second one the method for that class, but you'd have to rename the first argument to match in all methods.  The functions would need to have different names, `formFeedback.default` and `formFeedback.yourclass`.

There's also a more complicated system called S4 that can dispatch on the types of all arguments.

And you can craft your own dispatch if you like (and this is the basis for several other object systems in packages), using whatever method you like to decide which function to call.

Comment: I've seen both S3 and S4 solutions. My feeling is that S3 doesn't really offer much more than different functions, and S4 might be more useful if you want a lot of overloading of the same function. I might be wrong though. Could you elaborate when to use different functions, S3 and S4?

Comment: Nowadays I never use S4.  (Some people, e.g. those in the Bioconductor project, use S4 all the time:  so this might just be taste, not a reasoned decision.) Most packages I write use S3.   One advantage over simply having different function names is that the user doesn't need to know the class, e.g. they can call `print(x)` and expect something reasonable to show up; another is that fewer names exported makes documentation easier, both to write and to read.